# Extract underlying data from excel sheet into a table using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, pivot-table, drilldown

I am trying to extract Data from excel using SSIS. So basically, when i click on one of the cells of the excel file,a new sheet is created with new columns and new data corresponding to the cell I had just clicked.

I have no clue how to actually go straight to that newly created sheet from SSIS because that is the sheet containing the data I want to extract to SQL.

If anybody has done this before, please let me know how you did it.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the name of the sheet you need to extract data from?

Comment: Or do you know which sheets to not extract from?

Comment: The sheet I should extract data from is created once i click one of the cells. Depending on which cell i clicked on first, the new sheets get named sheet1, sheet2, sheet3.